# Python: searching through html file grabbing <a> tags with the href and text content

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, urllib

I need help with a solution to search through a html file with Python3 and retreive all of the `<a>` links on the page. Then appending the grabbed value to a dictionary with the adjacent href (url).

This is what I've already tried.

```
import urllib3
import re

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
my_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=AAPL"
a = http.request("GET",my_url)
html = a.data

links = re.finditer(' href="?([^\s^"]+)', html)

for link in links:
  print(link)
```

I'm getting this error...

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Thanks for your help.

I've also tried lxml...

```
links = lxml.html.parse("http://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=apple+stock&tbm=nws").xpath("//a/@href")
for link in links:
    print(link)
```

The result does not show all the links and I'm not sure why.

UPDATE:

New code =>

```
    def news_feed(self, stock):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    my_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s="+stock
    a = http.request("GET",my_url)
    html = a.data.decode('utf-8')
    xml = fromstring(html, HTMLParser())
    a_tags = xml.xpath("//a/@href")
    xml = fromstring(html, HTMLParser())
    a_tags = xml.xpath("//table[@id='yfncsumtab']//a")
    self.paired = dict((a.xpath(".//text()")[0].strip(), a.xpath("./@href")[0]) for a in a_tags)
    pp(self.paired)
```

Comment: `html = a.data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: You can parse this manually (using the suggestion from James), but I really think you should use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Awesome, that works. Should have known that!

Comment: I did try using BeautifulSoup but couldn't get it working in Python3 any suggestions?

Comment: @JamesBuck Okay so I've done that... Now each one comes out like this:  <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(34249, 34302), match=' href="https://in.finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s=[[li>

Comment: @PhilipCrocker It's a MatchObject. Try `print(link.group(1)`. See [MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) for more details

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your help! I'm fairly new to stack how can I give you cred? Or mark as answered?

Comment: @PhilipCrocker Don't worry about it ;). Wlecome to SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a html parser and decode the bytes as suggested, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) will make the job very easy and it a lot more reliable than a regex when parsing html:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
my_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=AAPL"
a = http.request("GET", my_url)
html = a.data.decode("utf-8")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print([a["href"] for a in BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("a",href=True)])
```

If you only  want the links starting with http you can use a css select:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print([a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href^=http]")])
```

Which will give you:

```
['https://edit.yahoo.com/config/eval_register?.src=quote&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h%3fs=AAPL', 'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=quote&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h%3fs=AAPL', 'https://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/finance/', 'http://in.yahoo.com/bin/set?cmp=uheader&src=others', 'https://in.mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=in&.lang=en-IN', 'http://in.my.yahoo.com', 'https://in.yahoo.com/', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/investing/', 'https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/170320-india-finance/category/84926-data-accuracy', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-bets-4-inch-iphone-112024627.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-iphone-faces-challenge-measuring-002248597.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/signs-life-apples-stock-wall-165820189.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-wins-appeal-patent-dispute-022120916.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/sharp-shares-plunge-foxconn-puts-031032213.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/solid-support-apple-iphone-encryption-121255578.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-apple-ratchet-rhetoric-fight-030713673.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/common-mobile-software-could-opened-030713243.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-likely-invoke-free-speech-030713050.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/bad-run-continues-freedom-251-092804374.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-appeals-court-upholds-apple-164738354.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-overtakes-apple-market-value-140918508.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-passes-apple-become-most-012844730.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-electronics-warns-difficult-2016-003517395.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-shares-seen-staying-muted-132628994.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/china-weakening-apple-turns-india-032020575.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-sees-first-sales-dip-011402926.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone-sales-weaker-expected-031840725.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-sells-fewer-iphones-expected-213516373.html', 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone-sales-weaker-expected-221908381.html', 'http://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/finance/basics/fitadelay2.html', 'http://billing.finance.yahoo.com/realtime_quotes/signup?.src=quote&.refer=quote', 'http://www.capitaliq.com', 'http://www.csidata.com', 'http://www.morningstar.com/']
```

To get the text and href:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

a_tags = soup.select("a[href^=http]")
from pprint import pprint as pp
paired = dict((a.text, a["href"]) for a in a_tags)

pp(paired)
```

Output:

```
 {u'Alphabet overtakes Apple in market value - for now': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-overtakes-apple-market-value-140918508.html',
 u'Alphabet passes Apple to become most valuable traded U.S. company': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-passes-apple-become-most-012844730.html',
 u'Apple bets new 4-inch iPhone to draw big-screen converts in China, India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-bets-4-inch-iphone-112024627.html',
 u'Apple iPhone sales weaker than expected': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone-sales-weaker-expected-221908381.html',
 u'Apple likely to invoke free-speech rights in encryption fight': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-likely-invoke-free-speech-030713050.html',
 u'Apple sees first sales dip in more than a decade as super-growth era falters': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-sells-fewer-iphones-expected-213516373.html',
 u'Apple shares fall most in two years in wake of earnings report': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-shares-seen-staying-muted-132628994.html',
 u"Apple's new iPhone faces challenge measuring up in China, India": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-iphone-faces-challenge-measuring-002248597.html',
 u"Bad run continues for 'Freedom 251', website down again on second day": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/bad-run-continues-freedom-251-092804374.html',
 u'Capital IQ': 'http://www.capitaliq.com',
 u'Commodity Systems, Inc. (CSI)': 'http://www.csidata.com',
 u'Download the new Yahoo Mail app': 'https://in.mobile.yahoo.com/mail/',
 u"EXCLUSIVE - Common mobile software could have opened San Bernardino shooter's iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/common-mobile-software-could-opened-030713243.html',
 u'Foxconn says in talks with Sharp over deal hitch; hopes for agreement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/sharp-shares-plunge-foxconn-puts-031032213.html',
 u'Help': 'https://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/finance/',
 u'Mail': 'https://in.mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=in&.lang=en-IN',
 u'Markets': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/investing/',
 u'Morningstar, Inc.': 'http://www.morningstar.com/',
 u'My Yahoo': 'http://in.my.yahoo.com',
 u'New User? Register': 'https://edit.yahoo.com/config/eval_register?.src=quote&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h%3fs=AAPL',
 u'Report an Issue': 'https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/170320-india-finance/category/84926-data-accuracy',
 u'Samsung Elec warns of difficult 2016 as smartphone troubles spread': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-electronics-warns-difficult-2016-003517395.html',
 u'Samsung wins appeal in patent dispute with Apple': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-wins-appeal-patent-dispute-022120916.html',
 u'Sign In': 'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=quote&.intl=in&.lang=en-IN&.done=https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/h%3fs=AAPL',
 u"Signs of life for Apple's stock as Wall St eyes new iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/signs-life-apples-stock-wall-165820189.html',
 u'Solid support for Apple in iPhone encryption fight - Reuters/Ipsos': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/solid-support-apple-iphone-encryption-121255578.html',
 u'U.S. appeals court upholds Apple e-book settlement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-appeals-court-upholds-apple-164738354.html',
 u'U.S., Apple ratchet up rhetoric in fight over encryption': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-apple-ratchet-rhetoric-fight-030713673.html',
 u'With China weakening, Apple turns to India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/china-weakening-apple-turns-india-032020575.html',
 u'Yahoo': 'https://in.yahoo.com/',
 u'Yahoo India Finance': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com',
 u'other exchanges': 'http://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/finance/basics/fitadelay2.html',
 u'premium service.': 'http://billing.finance.yahoo.com/realtime_quotes/signup?.src=quote&.refer=quote'}
```

The `a[href^=http]` means give me all the a tags that have href's and those href's  values  start with *http*.

Using *lxml* and using the *table id* to get just the story links which you are probably most interested in:

```
from lxml.etree  import fromstring, HTMLParser

xml = fromstring(_html, HTMLParser())

a_tags = xml.xpath("//table[@id='yfncsumtab']//a")

paired = dict((a.xpath(".//text()")[0].strip(), a.xpath("./@href")[0]) for a in a_tags)
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(paired)
```

Gives you:

```
{'Alphabet overtakes Apple in market value - for now': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-overtakes-apple-market-value-140918508.html',
 'Alphabet passes Apple to become most valuable traded U.S. company': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-passes-apple-become-most-012844730.html',
 'Apple bets new 4-inch iPhone to draw big-screen converts in China, India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-bets-4-inch-iphone-112024627.html',
 'Apple iPhone sales weaker than expected': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone-sales-weaker-expected-221908381.html',
 'Apple likely to invoke free-speech rights in encryption fight': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-likely-invoke-free-speech-030713050.html',
 'Apple sees first sales dip in more than a decade as super-growth era falters': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-sells-fewer-iphones-expected-213516373.html',
 'Apple shares fall most in two years in wake of earnings report': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-shares-seen-staying-muted-132628994.html',
 "Apple's new iPhone faces challenge measuring up in China, India": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-iphone-faces-challenge-measuring-002248597.html',
 "Bad run continues for 'Freedom 251', website down again on second day": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/bad-run-continues-freedom-251-092804374.html',
 "EXCLUSIVE - Common mobile software could have opened San Bernardino shooter's iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/common-mobile-software-could-opened-030713243.html',
 'Foxconn says in talks with Sharp over deal hitch; hopes for agreement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/sharp-shares-plunge-foxconn-puts-031032213.html',
 'Older Headlines': '/q/h?s=AAPL&t=2016-01-27T03:49:08+05:30',
 'Samsung Elec warns of difficult 2016 as smartphone troubles spread': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-electronics-warns-difficult-2016-003517395.html',
 'Samsung wins appeal in patent dispute with Apple': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-wins-appeal-patent-dispute-022120916.html',
 "Signs of life for Apple's stock as Wall St eyes new iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/signs-life-apples-stock-wall-165820189.html',
 'Solid support for Apple in iPhone encryption fight - Reuters/Ipsos': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/solid-support-apple-iphone-encryption-121255578.html',
 'U.S. appeals court upholds Apple e-book settlement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-appeals-court-upholds-apple-164738354.html',
 'U.S., Apple ratchet up rhetoric in fight over encryption': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-apple-ratchet-rhetoric-fight-030713673.html',
 'With China weakening, Apple turns to India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/china-weakening-apple-turns-india-032020575.html'}
```

We can do the same with out select:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(_html)

a_tags = soup.select("#yfncsumtab a")
from pprint import pprint as pp
paired = dict((a.text, a["href"]) for a in a_tags)
pp(paired)
```

Which will match our lxml output:

```
{u'Alphabet overtakes Apple in market value - for now': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-overtakes-apple-market-value-140918508.html',
 u'Alphabet passes Apple to become most valuable traded U.S. company': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/alphabet-passes-apple-become-most-012844730.html',
 u'Apple bets new 4-inch iPhone to draw big-screen converts in China, India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-bets-4-inch-iphone-112024627.html',
 u'Apple iPhone sales weaker than expected': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone-sales-weaker-expected-221908381.html',
 u'Apple likely to invoke free-speech rights in encryption fight': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-likely-invoke-free-speech-030713050.html',
 u'Apple sees first sales dip in more than a decade as super-growth era falters': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-sells-fewer-iphones-expected-213516373.html',
 u'Apple shares fall most in two years in wake of earnings report': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-shares-seen-staying-muted-132628994.html',
 u"Apple's new iPhone faces challenge measuring up in China, India": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-iphone-faces-challenge-measuring-002248597.html',
 u"Bad run continues for 'Freedom 251', website down again on second day": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/bad-run-continues-freedom-251-092804374.html',
 u"EXCLUSIVE - Common mobile software could have opened San Bernardino shooter's iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/common-mobile-software-could-opened-030713243.html',
 u'Foxconn says in talks with Sharp over deal hitch; hopes for agreement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/sharp-shares-plunge-foxconn-puts-031032213.html',
 u'Older Headlines': '/q/h?s=AAPL&t=2016-01-27T03:49:08+05:30',
 u'Samsung Elec warns of difficult 2016 as smartphone troubles spread': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-electronics-warns-difficult-2016-003517395.html',
 u'Samsung wins appeal in patent dispute with Apple': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-wins-appeal-patent-dispute-022120916.html',
 u"Signs of life for Apple's stock as Wall St eyes new iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/signs-life-apples-stock-wall-165820189.html',
 u'Solid support for Apple in iPhone encryption fight - Reuters/Ipsos': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/solid-support-apple-iphone-encryption-121255578.html',
 u'U.S. appeals court upholds Apple e-book settlement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-appeals-court-upholds-apple-164738354.html',
 u'U.S., Apple ratchet up rhetoric in fight over encryption': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/u-apple-ratchet-rhetoric-fight-030713673.html',
 u'With China weakening, Apple turns to India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/china-weakening-apple-turns-india-032020575.html'}
```

You could just  use `//*[@id='yfncsumtab']//a` as id's should be unique.

To get the first six links from the table using an xpath, we can use the ul's and extract the first 6 using `ul[position() < 7]`:

```
a_tags  = xml.xpath("//*[@id='yfncsumtab']//ul[position() < 7]//a")

paired = dict((a.xpath("./text()")[0].strip(), a.xpath("./@href")[0]) for a in a_tags)
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(paired)
```

Which will give you:

```
{'Apple bets new 4-inch iPhone to draw big-screen converts in China, India': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-bets-4-inch-iphone-112024627.html',
 "Apple's new iPhone faces challenge measuring up in China, India": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/apples-iphone-faces-challenge-measuring-002248597.html',
 'Foxconn says in talks with Sharp over deal hitch; hopes for agreement': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/sharp-shares-plunge-foxconn-puts-031032213.html',
 'Samsung wins appeal in patent dispute with Apple': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-wins-appeal-patent-dispute-022120916.html',
 "Signs of life for Apple's stock as Wall St eyes new iPhone": 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/signs-life-apples-stock-wall-165820189.html',
 'Solid support for Apple in iPhone encryption fight - Reuters/Ipsos': 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/news/solid-support-apple-iphone-encryption-121255578.html'}
```

For small tables, you could also simply slice.

Comment: I made the mistake of *not* using BeautifulSoup in one of my projects.

Comment: @BAH, it makes life very easy , even  if you knew next to nothing about html,  with a quick read of the docs you would be up and running in no time.

Comment: I did try using BeautifulSoup but couldn't get it working in Python3 any suggestions?

Comment: @PhilipCrocker,  how did it not work? If you have lxml installed that will also work and is an exceptionally good way to parse html

Comment: Don't worry. I've sorted it. Using bs4 was the key!

Comment: Could you suggest any way that I can get the text of the <a> tag adjacent as well as the href url? For my project I need to display a list of urls on my Python Django page.

Comment: yep, I will add a way with bs4 and lxml

Comment: Brilliant thanks for all your help. One last question! How in python3 can I get the value of a dictionary item without passing in the key?

Comment: Also how to I make it so it only gets the first 5 links from the site?

Comment: @PhilipCrocker,  If you just wanted the first six you can set a limit using find_all. `[a["href"] for a in BeautifulSoup(html).find_all("a", href=True, limit=6)]`, you could also just slice the list the select returns, in css you can use nth-child but bs4 only supports a subset which of the full css commands.

Comment: Does the dict only have a single key? If it does `next(iter(d.values()))` or `list(d.values())[0]` would get it

Comment: Hmm okay, what about using the way I used in the end? I'll post my code in the main question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will be back on in a bit and will throw together some examples